# Best size of page to display in webview

Tags: iphone

I want to creat a php page named contact us especially for iphone to display it in webview.current page of contact us on website is large and its visibly it not good looking in webView.

What size of page should i made in order to diplay it clearly in iphone UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking is "What is it about my current page design that makes it unsuitable for display on the iPhone?" When you figure that out, you'll know how to fix your login screen. (Although since you seem concerned about screen size, my guess is your design is too busy/complicated and expects/assumes a large screen size. Consider simplifying your HTML and CSS, and reducing your overall design to only what's necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several meta tags you can send to Mobile Safari that will lock the scale factor or the px width of the web page.  This may help manage how you want your page to show up.  For instance I use this on a small page that I want to show up at 1:1 scale on my iPhone (I use it for icon visibility testing).

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no"/>
```